# Insert chart at specific location in ms word using c# with xceed namespace

Tags: c#, ms-word, pie-chart, xceed

I have created the PieChart in c#.net using xceed.words.net namespace and I'm trying to insert that chart in ms Word.
But that chart is inserting at the last page of that document.
But i need that chart to insert at specific location in that document.
For example : my document has 8 pages I need to insert that chat at 3 pages at middle.. But that chart is inserting at last page that is 8th page.

```
Var p= new PieChart() ;
Int32 a=0,b=0;
Var c=new list<chartdata>() 
{
New chartdata() {cycle="USA",initial=a},
New chartdata() {cycle="canada",initial=b}
}
Var s1=new series("country") ;
s1. Bind(c, "cycle", " Initial") ;
p. Addseries(s1) ;
Var para= doc. InsertParagraph("chart") ;                            
doc. InsertChartAfterParagraph(p, para, 300,500) ;     

This is what I have written.. But that chart is inserting at end of 
the document .. But I need that at specific location


Did anybody knows about this please help me.. 
Thank you
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not supported yet.
you can refer to github issue `https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX/issues/156`.

You can try creating a paragraph at a specific location and try appending chart to it.

Comment: Var para= doc. InsertParagraph("chart") ;                             doc. InsertChartAfterParagraph(p, para, 300,500) ;       I have use this code but that paragraph also inserted at last page only